# Can we make managing recurring events easier?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, community-bulletin

[My site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) uses community events heavily; we have week-long events every week (plus a dozen or so others), which occur on a repeating schedule, like this:

[image: community bulletin]

The events occur each year in (generally) the same order, but the dates change by a few days each year.

We don't have to recreate those events every year; we can edit past ones:

[image: last year's event entry]

But the process is a little tedious, because we have to update both dates manually, either using the calendar picker (stepping through an entire year's worth of months) or by typing out the date in full:

[image: editing last year's event]

Because [only moderators can edit these entries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266021/162102), this maintenance falls on just a few of us, and it's kind of tedious.  Can we make it a little easier?

At the very least, when we copy an event, could the copy's start date be advanced to "today"?  There's no point in creating an event in the past, after all.  Ideally the end date would be advanced to "today + last year's interval", though leaving it blank is also an option.  These dates might still be *wrong*, but they'll be a lot closer to the right date, meaning a lot less mouse-action.

Beyond that, could we have the end date automatically update when the start date is edited?  This should probably only happen if the edited start date creates an invalid date range (end < start).  This introduces some UX complexities, I know, and maybe they're insurmountable (or just not worth the effort for an uncommon use case).

This is a support request, not a feature request, so please suggest anything that might solve my problem even if the specific date-range ideas don't work.

I'm asking this here on MSE rather than on our own meta because I know that other sites use time-based community events too, though I wouldn't be surprised if we're the heaviest users of this feature.

Comment: Space.SE has some *very* heavy use of this - you might have competition for the "uses this most" post :)

Comment: @ǝpoɔɟoʇɹɐ ok, good to know.  Not meant to be a competition. :-)  If their mods have tips to make this easier, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @ǝpoɔɟoʇɹɐ out of curiosity, what kinds of events does Space use?  (I don't see anything there currently, but I haven't followed the site.)

Comment: Vehicle launches, mostly, mixed with important ground events.